# A word for protector of nature/animals

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a Latin word that describes a person who:

- protects (is a guardian)
- is kind to
- takes responsibility of
- is kind of a deity

for animals or for nature.
Is there a certain word for that?

Comment: Welcome to the site! That list of four properties is a tall order. Can you think of a suitable word in English or any other language?

Comment: I couldn't find a single word for it in English or any other language, it doesn't have to satisfy/mean each of these, but as close as possible to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In translation there is a problem known as '[false friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend).' If you are translating French you have to take care not to translate 'sensible' as sensible. In Latin 'tutor' invites the translation '[tutor](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tutor):' "A private teacher, typically one who teaches a single pupil or a very small group."

Pastor also has overtones; and (as with tutor) this subtext may suit you or be an annoyance:

> [Pastor](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506175341/http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/getobject.pl?c.14:796.LewisShort18):  shepherd
> boni pastoris esse tondere pecus, non deglubere, Suet. Tib. 32.
> 1    A keeper: pavonum, Varr R. R. 3, 6, 5: columbarius, id. ib. 3, 7, 5: gallinarum, Col. 8, 2, 7: anserum, Dlg. 32, 1, 66.—
> (the idea of a shepherd is to shear the sheep, not to flay them)

You could reverse this by using [Aegis](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aegis) a word that in English means "The protection, backing, or support of a particular person;" and in Latin means a shield belonging to a god, occasionally a metaphor for any protection. I hope that covers divine protection in a metaphorical way with the right overtones.

> [Aegis](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:1181.lewisandshort) (Lewis/Short) A The shield of Jupiter, Verg. A. 8, 354; Sil. 12, 720.—
> B The shield of Minerva, with Medusa's head, Verg. A. 8, 435: contra sonantem Palladis aegida, Hor. C. 3, 4, 57; so Ov. M. 2, 753; 6, 78 al.

'Upilio' ([Lewis/Short Dictionary](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.19:269.lewisandshort))is free of these complications.

> ūpĭlĭo (eollat. form of ōpĭlĭo, q. v.), ōnis, m. ovis,
> **I:** a shepherd, Verg. E. 10, 19; App. Mag. p. 279, 35.

Comment: Do you mean that _tutor_ is here a false friend? If so, it's an extraordinary idea. The underlying concept is of protection, in every English sense, as the questioner requires. On the other hand _pastor_ (derived from _pascor_) is at root a herdsman, one who feeds his flock, etc. Can I invite you to reconsider your answer?

Comment: @TomCotton I'm not trying to speak for Hugh or Glorfindel, but the English word "tutor", at least here in the USA, means a guy who helps you with your schoolwork. The Latin word *tutor* means so much more than just that.

Answer (score 5):

The word that you want is *tutor, -oris*. The verb that describes all the functions you require is the regular, 1st conjugation deponent *tutor, tutari, tutatus*, and an associated adjective is *tutelaris*.

[In English, a 'tutelary deity' is a 'protective spirit'.]

Comment: I do like *tutelaris*, especially in light of the last bullet point. *Numen tutelare* has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 4):

This might be in the wrong direction, but one option I suggest considering is ***Diana*** (cf. Greek Artemis).
She is a goddess who is a kind guardian of animals.
Admittedly it is a proper noun, but in some contexts you can speak of someone as a Diana.

Answer (score 3):

I think [*custos*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcustos) works pretty well, too:

> a guard, watch, preserver, keeper, overseer, protector, defender, attendant, etc., protectress, etc., in a friendly or hostile sense (freq. and class.).

Answer (score 2):

Many here have answered *tutor*, which is an excellent suggestion. A closely related alternative is *tutela*. It is a slightly more abstract word, and it can also refer to that which is protected (the "ward" if you will). But given sufficient context, *tutela* could work as well as *tutor*.

Comment: +1 for the very root of 'tutelary.' I think this certainly works despite the passive meaning, since the passive sense is only found in Augustan poets (and one iffy use in Cicero), at least as far as I can tell from Lewis and Short.